# How can a C# program use a C++ dll of any version?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, version

We're creating a dll, written in C++, providing access to some hardware. We also have a C# program that uses this dll.

We're having an issue with the versions. Indeed, when running the C# program, it absolutely wants to use the exact C++ dll version it used when compiling. I.e. if the C# program was compiled using C++ dll 1.2.3.4, then the program will refuse to run with C++ dll 1.2.3.5.

I'd like to instruct the C# program to use any C++ dll with version 1.2.anything.

Where can I configure this in the C# project?

This question has been superseded by [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595655/how-can-a-c-sharp-program-use-a-com-dll-of-any-version), more related to COM.

Comment: How does your C# program use this dll?

Comment: Do you use C++/CLI assembly ? Please add some details on how you build your soft...

Comment: @alexbuisson The dll is not using C++/CLI. The dll is compiled to native executable.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing this fancy exists in C++.  Using a side-by-side manifest technically permits this but you would have known about it since you would have typed the version number in the manifest of your C# program.

The far more likely explanation is that you actually created a C++/CLI assembly.  Many programmers confuse C++/CLI with C++.  Easy mistake since that language permits using native C++ code.  But it actually gets compiled to a *mixed-mode* assembly, an assembly that contains both IL and native code.  The normal CLR version checking occurs for such an assembly when the CLR loads it, it is only happy with an exact version match.  A strong DLL Hell counter-measure.

And the normal CLR version wrangling option is available to bypass this check, a `<bindingRedirect>` element in your app.exe.config file.  As well as controlling the assembly version number the way you do it for your C# code so this isn't necessary.

The easiest way to check if this guess is accurate is by using Project + Add Reference and select the DLL.  If that doesn't draw any complaint and the assembly gets added to the References node of your C# project then you *know* it is a normal .NET assembly.  Don't forget to take advantage of that, no pinvoke required.

Answer (score 1):

Load the dll at runtime and use reflection to call it's methods.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\test.dll");

Assembly.GetTypes();

Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Can you not load a C++ dll dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to configure your program to use 1.2.* version and no others. Unless you would write the code for that on your own. Another possibility would be not to change the version tag of the C++ dll, but it does not seem you want to that.

A solution avoiding the version dependency would be the usage of dllimport. You can load any dll written in C++ with it. It is free of version dependency. See the example from the msdn and link at the end:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{
 // Use DllImport to import the Win32 MessageBox function.
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);

 static void Main()
 {
     // Call the MessageBox function using platform invoke.
    MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
 }
```

}

[Description in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)